# Trigger submit with prevent default

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, submit

I'm trying to call submit method on form via refs from my script. On form tag I have `@submit.prevent`.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <form ref="search-form" @submit.prevent="sub">
      <input type="text" required />
    </form>
    <button @click="submitForm">click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      this.$refs["search-form"].submit();
    },
    sub() {
      console.log("submitted");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

My problems are that when I click button:

- page get reloaded like prevent default is not working
- sub() is not called at all

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear what you want to do but maybe you need this

```js
    const app = new Vue({
      methods: {
       submitForm() {
      this.$refs["search-form"].submit();
    },
    sub() {
    alert('hello');
    },
      }
    })
    app.$mount("#app")
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  
  <div id="app">
    <form ref="search-form" @submit.prevent="sub">
        <input type="text" required/>
       <button @click.native.prevent="submitForm">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <form ref="search-form">
      <input type="text" required />
    </form>
    <button @click.stop.prevent="processForm">click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    processForm() {
      // validation here
      this.$refs["search-form"].onsubmit = this.submitForm();
    },
    submitForm() {
      // AJAX here
      console.log("submitted");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

⚠️ I assume that when you use `prevent` means you are going to manually submit the form at a later stage (maybe after client side validation). Then its either you use AJAX or Axios to submit the form to the server side. Calling `submit()` anywhere here will still reload your page.